# Magento2.4 sort by created date not working

Tags: magento2, sorting

Magento2.4 Sort by created date not working on list page

```
    case 'new_arrivals':
$this->_collection->getSelect()->order('e.created_at '. $this->getCurrentDirection());
break;
```

It just says there are no products to display

Comment: There is no problem in you above code. Please share more code here, like how you are getting this collection

Comment: I have the same problem using the same code from a plugin. Since using ElasticSearch as Magento default it no longer works.